# Ng-hide and show in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the button to toggle only on the one clicked, but as I am using ng-repeat, it all changes together. How do i fix it so that it would only change on the one clicked?

HTML:

```
        <ul>
            <li class="displaySubCategory" ng-repeat="communityTheme in community | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
              <div class="categoryImg">
                <img src="img/csvIcon.png" />
                <img src="img/shpIcon.png" />
              </div>
              <div class="categoryDesc">
                <p>{{communityTheme.THEMENAME}}</p>
                <a ng-href="https://assets.onemap.sg/shp/{{SHPFile}}" ng-click="getSHP(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" target="_blank" download>SHP</a> |
                <a ng-href="https://assets.onemap.sg/kml/{{KMLFile}}" ng-click="getKML(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" target="_blank" download>KML</a> |
                <a href="" ng-show="viewMarker" ng-click="getMapData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)">View on Map</a>
                <a href="" ng-hide="viewMarker" ng-click="getMapData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)">Remove Marker</a>
                <!-- <a href="" ng-click="getData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" download>View Data</a> -->
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

JS:

```
        $scope.viewMarker = true;
        $scope.getMapData = function (msg) {
        $scope.viewMarker = !$scope.viewMarker;
        }
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Modified code:

```js
            $scope.viewMarker = true;
            $scope.getMapData = function (msg, passedIndex) {
              if($scope.community[passedIndex].visibility)
              {
                $scope.community[passedIndex].visibility =false;
              }  else {
                $scope.community[passedIndex].visibility = true;
              }

              $scope.viewMarker = !$scope.viewMarker;
```

```html
<ul>
     <li class="displaySubCategory" ng-repeat="communityTheme in community | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
       <div class="categoryImg">
         <img src="img/csvIcon.png" />
         <img src="img/shpIcon.png" />
       </div>
       <div class="categoryDesc">
         <p>{{communityTheme.THEMENAME}}</p>
         <a ng-href="https://assets.onemap.sg/shp/{{SHPFile}}" ng-click="getSHP(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" target="_blank" download>SHP</a> |
         <a ng-href="https://assets.onemap.sg/kml/{{KMLFile}}" ng-click="getKML(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" target="_blank" download>KML</a> |
         <a href="" ng-show="viewMarker" ng-click="getMapData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME, $index)">View on Map</a>
         <a href="" ng-hide="viewMarker" ng-click="getMapData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME, $index)">Remove Marker</a>
         <!-- <a href="" ng-click="getData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" download>View Data</a> -->
       </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: put a Boolean variable for visibility in community array... toggle its value...

Comment: how do i do that @@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help clarify...

```js
        var app = angular.module("test", []); 
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.community  = [
                { THEMENAME:"Milk", QUERYNAME:"Milk", visibility:true}
                , { THEMENAME:"Bread", QUERYNAME:"Milk", visibility:true}
                , { THEMENAME:"Cheese", QUERYNAME:"Milk", visibility:true}
                ];

            $scope.getMapData = function(passedQueryName, passedIndex){
                /*do what you were doing, just add this one more point*/
                
                if($scope.community[passedIndex].visibility) {$scope.community[passedIndex].visibility =false;}
                else {$scope.community[passedIndex].visibility = true;}

            }

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>  


<div ng-app="test">


                
                <div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                  
                    <div ng-repeat="communityTheme in community ">
                        {{x}}
                        <div class="categoryDesc">
                            <p>{{communityTheme.THEMENAME}} @ {{$index}}</p>
                            <a ng-href="https://assets.onemap.sg/shp/{{SHPFile}}" ng-click="getSHP(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" target="_blank" download>SHP</a> |
                            <a ng-href="https://assets.onemap.sg/kml/{{KMLFile}}" ng-click="getKML(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" target="_blank" download>KML</a> |
                            <a href="" ng-show="communityTheme.visibility" ng-click="getMapData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME, $index)">View on Map</a>
                            <a href="" ng-hide="communityTheme.visibility" ng-click="getMapData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME, $index)">Remove Marker</a>
                            <!-- <a href="" ng-click="getData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" download>View Data</a> -->
                        </div>

                    </div>
                  
                </div>

                <p>So far we have made an HTML list based on the items of an array.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I edited to show u how i modified mine, is there something wrong? It isn't working

Comment: @HangulSR you didn't add the visibility as a field in the array 'community'... do this also

Comment: @Alqbal is there any other workaround if i dont add a new field in?

Comment: @HangulSR You want to have visibility at each item's level... so the visibility-variable has to be at each item's level also; you can write jQuery to toggle CSS classes also... but that like putting bicycle tyres on a sports car; AngularJS is super - best that you use it.

Comment: But the data i have is fetched from a api, unless i push a new array in, which doesn't sound that good me. My bad for not stating properly tho. Still thanks for the help and explanation!

Comment: @HangulSR It is perfectly ok to fetch from an API, just make sure that the array to which you map the response from the api has this additional visibility field (which you would initialize to true by-default);... Thanks for accepting the answer. good luck in you tech tasks :)

Comment: @Alqbal, if i set my remove marker to another function, it says my passindex is not defined, any way to fix that?

Comment: you can pass to any function, but it should be defined within the controller definition... make sure that you are passing the IndexNumber as a parameter at the time of function call; in case of issues, update your question with the code and drop me a message and I will respond

Answer (score 0):

As i see now you are using the same variable to handle the toggling part. you should have an individual variable with a boolean value to handle the toggling so that you can handle each element individually.

**[`DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/yFzFJOxh6aXNLqB9Dpg8?p=preview)**

Comment: How to do that? Could u please provide an example for me? And thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using it like the below code where we'll be creating dynamic variable 'viewMarker' in the same object and to consider it's default value as 'false' and to toggle it in the getMapData function by inverting its value.

**Template:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="displaySubCategory" ng-repeat="communityTheme in community | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
        <div class="categoryImg">
            <img src="img/csvIcon.png" />
            <img src="img/shpIcon.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="categoryDesc">
            <p>{{communityTheme.THEMENAME}}</p>
            <a ng-href="https://assets.onemap.sg/shp/{{SHPFile}}" ng-click="getSHP(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" target="_blank" download>SHP</a> |
            <a ng-href="https://assets.onemap.sg/kml/{{KMLFile}}" ng-click="getKML(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" target="_blank" download>KML</a> |
            <a href="" ng-show="communityTheme.viewMarker" ng-click="getMapData(communityTheme)">View on Map</a>
            <a href="" ng-hide="communityTheme.viewMarker" ng-click="getMapData(communityTheme)">Remove Marker</a>
            <!-- <a href="" ng-click="getData(communityTheme.QUERYNAME)" download>View Data</a> -->
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.getMapData = function (obj) {
    obj.viewMarker = !obj.viewMarker;
}
```